# How to use NetSpeed with LXDE?

Tags: gnome, lxde, lxpanel

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with LXDE because I prefer minimalism and functionality. GNOME 3 is unacceptably heavy on system resources. MATE (based on GNOME 2) is much better, but still too heavy. There is a GNOME applet called "NetSpeed" that I really like. It displays real time download and upload speed number (as in picture) on MATE panel and it works perfectly with MATE, but not with lxpanel on LXDE. Please let me know how to make it work with LXDE. Thank you.

Summary:

1. It must display the speed as number in KiB/s or B/s - not as a graph.
2. It must display the speed inside the lxpanel - not on a desktop.[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, but that didn't answer my question: Can NetSpeed applet work with lxpanel on LXDE. The latest MATE version is 1.24 released in 2020. The "netspeed" applet is a part of the mate-applets package and works with mate-panel. However I couldn't make it work with lxpanel. Any relevant information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. My goal is to display real time download/upload speed in lxpanel. It doesn't have to be the NetSpeed applet. Any applet that works with lxpanel is fine. I already use MATE 1.24 with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and netspeed applet on my newer hardware and it works great. However, on my older laptop I prefer to use LXDE since it is lighter than MATE.

Comment: I installed the package indicator-multiload. The shortcut "System Load Indicator" was added to the main menu, however nothing happens when I click on the shortcut.

Comment: Actually, the closest alternative to "netspeed" is "cbm" cbm (0.2-5) [universe] https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/cbm (display in real time the network traffic speed). Unfortunately, it only works in terminal emulator and not inside the lxpanel, which is inconvenient. Otherwise, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [`indicator-multiload`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/indicator-multiload) by

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
```

then configure it to show only network graph and use inside LXPanel.

---

Other lightweight alternatives may be [Conky](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/conky) or [GNU Krell Monitors](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gkrellm).

Comment: I've tried many options, but none achieves a very simple thing, - to display real time download speed number as "x B/s" or "x MiB/s" - not as a graph and not outside of the always visible panel.

Comment: Then switch to MATE fully. It works great even on Intel Atom or AMD E1 with 1 Gb of RAM.

Comment: OK, I installed mate-panel and mate-applets, then replaced lxpanel with mate-panel in default startup applications. The netspeed works fine, but the MATE menu doesn't. MATE DE is OK and it does work on Atom CPUs (mine is Apollo Lake Celeron J3355), however MATE still feels heavy and works with some delays. LXDE works instantly and I prefer lxmenu. To me nothing beats LXDE in speed vs functionality. May be JWM or i3 are faster, but they lack the functionality and look ugly. LXDE is extremely fast, stable and I can make it look exactly the way I want. The only thing missing is the "netspeed".

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered XFCE?  It's not as light as LXDE, but it is lighter than MATE.  Network Monitor is customizable, and is always visible in the XFCE panel.  I have it installed on my 2011 netbook, and with just few adjustments, to the panel configuration, it looks just like MATE.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I can tolerate XFCE, but I cannot make it look the way I like. From all the DE choices I like LXDE as absolutely the best for my needs and taste. MATE is my 2nd choice. MATE is light enough, but it includes too many packages that I don't use, but cannot remove (caja, mate themes, icons, etc.) The only file manager I like is PCManFM. I always install and use PCManFM on MATE and ignore Caja, which I don't like. Thanks again for your input, but I would rather use MATE than XFCE, and in my installation MATE consumed less RAM than XFCE, while looking way better.